# JMockit multiple exceptions as result for method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

This is from the official JMockit Tutorial:

```
@Test
   public void doSomethingHandlesSomeCheckedException() throws Exception
   {
      new Expectations() {
         DependencyAbc abc;

         {
            abc.stringReturningMethod();
            returns("str1", "str2");
            result = new SomeCheckedException();
         }
      };

      new UnitUnderTest().doSomething();
   }
```

Is it possible to state the opposite, that is multiple results and one return - I need to throw 2 exceptions and only then return a good value. Something like this is what Im looking for:

```
  abc.stringReturningMethod();
  returns(new SomeCheckedException(), new SomeOtherException(),"third");
```

This doesn't work, JMockit can't cast those exceptions to `String` (which is the return type of `stringReturningMethod`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
    abc.stringReturningMethod();
    result = new SomeCheckedException();
    result = new SomeOtherException();
    result = "third";
```

Comment: Won't it set the result for all three calls as `third`?

Comment: Nope. It will record three consecutive results for the `stringReturningMethod()`. (A "result" is either a value to return, an exception to throw, or a `Delegate` to execute. JMockit automatically rewrites these assignments as invocations to its internal methods, that's why it works.)

Comment: This doesn't work. You have to do `result = new SomeCheckedException(); result = new SomeOtherException(); returns("Non-exception-String-value");`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a shortcut to do that but you could always record that the method will be called several times:

```
abc.stringReturningMethod();
result = new SomeCheckedException();

abc.stringReturningMethod();
result = new SomeOtherException();

abc.stringReturningMethod();
result = "third";
```

Comment: I feel like this did NOT work for me I tried it, I tried abc.getCode() result = 1;  then abc.getCode() result = new RuntimeException() and it did not work correctly...  the other answer worked, however.